# Issues with Blazor wasm authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am having an issue with Blazor WASM authentication which is reproduced here:

https://github.com/jahnotto/authfrust

Note that there is an @attribute [Authorize] at the top of the Home.razor page. Other than that, this is based on the Blazor wasm template in Visual Studio 2023.

When running locally, it works fine. However, after publishing it to an Azure App server, it doesn't work:

Chrome on Windows: if I open a new browser instance (after quitting the browser completetely), the page seems to forward to the usual "processing login", before it ends up with an error message saying "There was an error trying to log you in: '"undefined" is not valid JSON'". If I re-enter the URL or open another tab, it works fine. This happens regardless on whether I have been logged in previously.

Edge on Android tablet or Edge on iPad: In addition to the above behavor; if I remove the [Authorize] attribute on the Home page and click the Login button, a new tab is opened. The tab says "Completing login" and stays there forever.

Any clues?

Comment: Could you kindly check the solution below ? Please let me know if it works for you,many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known github issue, and Microsoft Product Group will fix it in the next version.

**Related Links**

1. [[release/8.0] Preserve RemoteAuthenticationContext during trimming if used in JS interop #54655](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/54655)
2. [Preserve RemoteAuthenticationContext during JS interop #54225](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/54225)
3. [Blazor WASM MSAL Published Application Gets Stuck on "Completing Login"](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52619)

[image]

[image]